# deploy logic apps visual studio 2022

Tags: azure-logic-apps, visual-studio-2022

I was using the Cloud Explorer to deploy logic apps to Azure in Visual Studio 2019.  Cloud Explorer has been retired as mentioned on [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/manage-logic-apps-with-visual-studio)
I saw a suggestion to use Azure storage explorer which I've downloaded.  That allows me to link to storage accounts in Azure, but logic apps are stored in resource groups.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, this is not supported seems like there is a feedback request already made in [Azure Logic Apps Tools does not Support Visual Studio 2022](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/34599c57-238b-ec11-a81b-0022484bfd94). You may upvote this recommendation to request it to be implemented as soon as possible.

Comment: I've upvoted the recommendation.  Is there a workaround using something mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/azure/vs-azure-tools-resources-managing-with-cloud-explorer?view=vs-2022

Comment: @AlHal one workaround is to download the arm template and edit it from vs2022 and deploy it to azure from the portal, else you can work in VS2019.

Comment: I can download the ARM template for a logic app using the instructions on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/export-template-portal.  What about parameter files for the logic app?

Comment: What I meant to say is, It won't be working anyway but for editing it manually, saving it, and again deploying through the portal it might work but again instead vs2022 , vS2019 is the only option that is fully working as of now.

Comment: ok.  I wonder what sort of future there is for logic apps.